# Performance of PHP array vs database

Tags: php, database, arrays, performance

I have a PHP file that contains a large array (about 90KB). I'm considering moving it to the database however I'm not sure it's worth the trouble.

In general, am I likely to run into problems with a 90KB array? Will I get any speed improvement by moving the data to a database?

Comment: Like John said, arrays are much faster. I've built a caching framework which stores arrays into files (like the one you're talking about) and it's amazing when it comes to performance. Brilliant for AJAX calls.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Arrays are *much* faster then accessing a database. Accessing a database is one of the more expensive things you can do in PHP while accessing an array is one of the fastest.

Comment: What if you only need to access one element? Doing a quick DB query on an indexed table might be faster than parsing a file and assigning 90 kB worth of array variables. There has to be a cross over somewhere where the DB query becomes more beneficial. What about things like sorting? Surely an indexed DB would be faster than an array.

Comment: Mike makes a good point, I wonder at what point it becomes inefficient to load a PHP array and faster to do a DB query.

Comment: Nope, not @ 90Kb.  This is small enough to get cached in the VFAT cache and even on a cache-miss will generate only one or two physical I/Os. The CPU overhead is trivial.  The main things are to (i)ensure that you only write back on dirtied content, and (ii) to have a contention strategy if you have parallel transactions.